# How to implement job migration fault tolerance technique in clousim?

Tags: github, machine-learning, virtual-machine, workflowservice, cloudsim

I want to implement job migration for the failed task in cloudsim.Is there any source code available available on gitHub etc?

Answer (score 0):

CloudSim does not implement Cloudlet migration or fault injection.

But if you want to use a modern, full-featured, state-of-the-art and easier-to-use fork of CloudSim, try [CloudSim Plus](https://github.com/manoelcampos/cloudsim-plus/blob/master/cloudsim-plus-examples/src/main/java/org/cloudsimplus/examples/HostFaultInjectionExample1.java). It has a fault-injection module that doesn't migrate Cloudlets, but when a VM fails due to a failure on its Hosts, a clone of that VM is created from a snapshot and the Cloudlets restarted.

To inject the failures and enable VM clones to be created, you can execute the following code:

```
long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();

//Creates a random number generator following the Poisson distribution
//MEAN_FAILURE_NUMBER_PER_HOUR is a constant you have to create
//to define the mean number of Host failures per hour.
ContinuousDistribution poisson = new PoissonDistr(MEAN_FAILURE_NUMBER_PER_HOUR, seed);

//The object that will inject random failures into Host's PEs.
HostFaultInjection fault = new HostFaultInjection(datacenter0, poisson);
fault.setMaxTimeToFailInHours(800);

//Defines a cloner function (cloneVm method) that will be called 
//when a VM from a given broker fails due to a Host failure.
//The call to addVmCloner also defines a method to clone the cloudlets
//running inside the failed VM. 
fault.addVmCloner(broker, new VmClonerSimple(this::cloneVm, this::cloneCloudlets)));
```

To check and understand the complete example, follow [this link](https://github.com/manoelcampos/cloudsim-plus/blob/master/cloudsim-plus-examples/src/main/java/org/cloudsimplus/examples/HostFaultInjectionExample1.java) and the [faulinjection package documentation](https://github.com/manoelcampos/cloudsim-plus/tree/master/cloudsim-plus/src/main/java/org/cloudsimplus/faultinjection) in CloudSim Plus.